# Display DB value for selected name and insert that name to another table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a drop down that display categories from database and it's display selected category price in textfield.[image: when select web development it's price display in textfield]

when select web development it's price(12) display in textfield

this is code for that

```
    <select name="category" class="form-control" id="category">
         <?php
          $query= "SELECT  * FROM category" ;
        $result= mysql_query($query);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {   
        echo '<option value="'.$row['cost_for_cat'].'">'.$row['cat_name'].'</option>';
                                                        }
            ?>      
     </select>

 <input name="cat_cost" id="cat_cost" type="text" value="<?php echo ('cost_for_cat'); ?>" onClick="checkprice()" class="form-control" placeholder="£" width="30" required/>

    <script>
        var select = document.getElementById('category');
        var input = document.getElementById('cat_cost');
        select.onchange = function(){
            input.value = select.value;
            }
    </script>
```

also i want to insert category name (Web Development) in another table when button click.but both values(cost_for_cat,cat_name) should come from "option value".like this

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['cost_for_cat'].'">'.$row['cat_name'].'</option>';
```

and

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['cat_name'].'">'.$row['cat_name'].'</option>';
```

is there any solution?please help.

Answer (score 0):

With the first problem, displaying the cost category when a category is selected, you have to use the "onchange" of you select element and retrieve the corresponding cost then put it on your textfield.
For the second thing, the category value as you said is already there and will be sent when the form submitted, for the text you can include a hidden input, get the text of the selected category and set it there.
The code you will need:

```
var categoryDropDownList = document.getElementById("category");
var selectedValue = categoryDropDownList.value;
var selectedText = categoryDropDownList.options[categoryDropDownList.selectedIndex].text;
```

Comment: I didn't get it.Could you please explain it in detail?